# How to find out differences between two timestamps and extract only hours and minutes

Tags: sql, oracle

How to find out the difference between two timestamps and get only hours and minutes from the difference? I tried using the extract function or doing straight subtraction but I am not getting the expected result.

```
select (to_timestamp('29-09-22 2:27:48.696000000 PM +05:30') - systimestamp)col from dual;
```

DB Version: Oracle SQL Developer (18c)

Comment: Please describe what does "*I am not getting the expected result*" mean. Timestamp with time zone is not the same as pure timestamp, which you are trying to get via `to_timestamp`. Try to use `to_timestamp_tz('2022-09-29 02:27:48.696000000 PM +05:30', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh12:mi:ss.ff PM TZH:TZM')`

Comment: If the difference could be more than 24 hours, and/or it could be negative, [then you might have to do a bit more work](https://dbfiddle.uk/u0ULdrjz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `EXTRACT`:

```sql
SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM diff)*24 + EXTRACT(HOUR FROM diff) AS hours,
       EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM diff) AS minutes
FROM   (
  select TIMESTAMP '2022-09-29 14:27:48.696000000 +05:30' - systimestamp AS diff
  from   dual
);
```

Which outputs:

| HOURS | MINUTES |
| --- | --- |
| 23 | 41 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GcT1X03K)